# Does GitHub support git:// protocol for pull?

Tags: git, github, pull

Is it possible to use such configuration? Or there are no advatages between ssh:// and git://?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does. However, the URL bar in github web page no loner have git protocol for copying the URL to clipboard. You have to replace https:// with git:// by yourself.

Also, git protocol use port 9418. Make sure you can use this port.

git protocol is not encrypted, but it is faster than https.

git protocol is read-only in github. You cannot push to it via git protocol.

Comment: ``https://`` is the recommended way of accessing GitHub repositories: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/.  Performance should be comparable between ``https://`` and ``git://``, since GitHub's update of Smart HTTP many years ago (https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support).  @viakondratiuk, no use of the ``git://`` protocol is recommended by GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

As of writing this answer, GitHub *does support* the `git://` protocol as read-only. It is the only supported protocol that is not encrypted or secured with keyed access.

As of March 15, 2022, GitHub *will no longer support* the `git://` protocol. As detailed in a blog post, there will be brownout periods leading up to the permanent removal of support for the `git://` protocol.

[Source](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/).   [Archive of source](https://web.archive.org/web/20211102031652/https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/).