# What protocol do I use when run `git clone`

Tags: git

[Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) specifies four protocols that can be used by GIT: `Local`, `HTTP`, `Secure Shell (SSH)` and `Git`. Is my understanding correct that when I clone a repository from github like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/test.git
```

I'm using `HTTP` protocol?

If I wanted to use GIT protocol, I'd need to clone the repository like this?

```
git clone git@github.com:maximusk/test.git
```

Comment: The protocol is not explicitly stored anywhere. It is detected from the URL when the URL is used (to `clone`, `fetch`, `push`, etc). The URL is stored as the `origin` remote of the cloned repo. Use `git remote -v` to see the URL or other [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) commands to handle the remotes.

Comment: You have three questions in one, making it too broad. All three, I'm sure, have also been asked and answered before. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: @axiac, that's interesting, thanks. I guess that's the simple answer to my question. One clarification, does it mean that I can clone using one protocol and push using the other?

Comment: You can see the protocol in GitHub when you click on the "Clone or Download" button: "Clone with SSH" or "Clone with HTTPS". Git protocol is [not there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317264/does-github-support-git-protocol-for-pull); and for obvious reasons, Local protocol does not apply to Github.

Comment: @Amadan, yes, that's what I did before asking the question

Comment: The answers to your questions are also provided (with examples) in the [Git book page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) you linked.

Comment: @axiac, yeah, thanks. So can you confirm that I can clone using one protocol and push using the other?

Comment: Indeed, you can configure [different URLs for `fetch` and `push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem) for a remote. But they must be only alternative ways to reach the same remote repository, not different repositories.

Comment: @axiac, interesting, thanks. Can you maybe put it as an answer

Comment: I've upvoted your question (not sure why it had the downvotes it had, there are subtleties here that go well beyond the existing documentation, some of which will matter soon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol is not explicitly stored anywhere. It is detected from the URL when the URL is used (to `clone`, `fetch`, `push`, etc).

When a repository is cloned, a remote named `origin` is created in the clone. The URL of the cloned repository is set as both `fetch` and `push` URLs of the `origin` remote of the new clone.

Use [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote--v) to see the URL(s) of each remote.
Use [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem) to change the URLs of a remote.

You can use different URLs for `fetch` and `push` but they must point to the same remote repository. If you want to `fetch` from one repository and `push` to a different repository then configure two different `remote`s.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is oriented towards the Git Pro book's discussion, which is really, technically, mainly dealing with what I think should be called *transports* rather than protocols.  The Git Pro book does not go into this distinction (at least at the time I write this answer); neither does the current Git documentation.  But [Git 2.18 has introduced a new wire protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3331758f12da22f4103eec7efe1b5304a9be5e9/Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt#L242) (with enabling code first appearing in [Git 2.16](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3331758f12da22f4103eec7efe1b5304a9be5e9/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L194-L196)), so I think this needs another answer to future-proof this question.

In particular, Git has a bad habit of conflating *authentication*, *permissions*, *transports* (in the sense of a "transport layer" in a networking stack), and *protocol* (what Git uses for Git-to-web-server or peer-to-peer communication).  This has been working so far for Git because:

- The local (`file://` or raw pathname) specifier results in using the local methods, which do no authentication and rely on OS permissions.<sup>1</sup>  Since your Git is just talking to itself, it merely has to agree with itself about what it is saying to itself.
- The `http://` and `https://` specifiers use libcurl and external authenticators to do authentication (if they do it at all).<sup>2</sup>  After that they rely on OS permissions.  Because Git is talking to a web server, it must smuggle its own protocol through the server's REST interface.  Meanwhile the web server itself provides the transport protocol.
- The `ssh://` specifier uses ssh, typically from an OS-provided library, to do authentication and transport.<sup>3</sup>  The OS at the other end provides any permissions checking in normal cases.  (Special cases such as Gitolite and GitHub-ssh-access use other tricks behind the scenes, all outside Git's purview.)
- The `git://` specifier uses a lightweight protocol atop TCP as a transport protocol.  It does no authentication and has no permissions checking.  It is purely read-only: it does not need anything to control who can push, since no one can push.<sup>4</sup>

Until Git 2.16, there really was only one Git wire protocol.  (The so-called "dumb protocol" is specific to using Web servers, and even then, only when they can't run a real protocol.  The dumb protocol really amounts to being able to download individual files from a web server—that's it!)  In Git 2.16, however, Git learned the ability to request a particular protocol version.

The existing smart protocol therefore became Git protocol version zero.  Git protocol version 1 was immediately defined as doing the same thing, so that it's possible to test the protocol version selection code without adding anything else.

In Git 2.18, however, there is now a protocol version 2.  Protocol 2 is still being defined, but the first and perhaps most useful (to some at least) trick it has is the ability to list fewer references.  Connecting to a large, older Git repository that has many tags, for instance, can produce massive wastes of bandwidth.  There are a lot of good details at [the Google blog page here](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-git-protocol-version-2.html).

For now, this kind of protocol numbering is still mainly for Git developers, but it is likely to become important soon.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's worth mentioning that the OS permissions on POSIX systems (Linux, the various BSDs, and so on) allow for *user*, *group*, and *other* permissions.  Here "user" means the numeric user-ID of whoever is running the various commands, "group" means the numeric group-ID, and "other" means anyone who does not first match "user" or "group".  That is, the actual permissions are determined by which of these three first match the current user's IDs.

While not nearly as fancy as full blown ACLs, Git takes advantage of these permissions to let the OS handle both local (same-host) and remote (any network transport) permissions-checking.  Specifically, you can configure `core.sharedRepository` to `group` or `all` or wire in a specific POSIX *umask* value.  For details, see [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

<sup>2</sup>Note that `https://` can use SSL/TLS and do encrypted data exchange.  That is, the REST operations, and all the data sent once Git gets connected across whatever protocol Git will use, are kept secret from intermediate sites, assuming no one breaks the encryption.  There are a number of configuration knobs in Git delivered to libcurl (though it's up to libcurl to *use* them).  See all of the `http.*` settings in `git config`.  SSL security is complex; see the link in footnote 3.

<sup>3</sup>SSH transport is encrypted a la SSL/TLS, though the details differ.  For more, see [Difference between SSH and SSL, especially in terms of "SFTP" vs. "FTP over SSL"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/723152/1256452).

<sup>4</sup>As [kostix noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099598/what-protocol-do-i-use-when-run-git-clone/51112344?noredirect=1#comment89218235_51112344), you can enable push over `git://` transports.  This seems like a very bad idea to me, precisely *because* there is no authentication and no permissions-checking.  Note that OS-level permissions checking is effectively short-circuited since the Git daemon serving `git://` requests is running as one particular user-ID, normally that of `git-daemon`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and your upvote! You're always helping me with Git. Appreciate

Comment: A very good writeup (as usually). Still, two minor nitpicks: 1) The HTTPS transport may also use SSL/TLS-level authentication (through X.509 certificates); in the latest to date Git-for-Windows releases it had even learned to use Windows-native system/user certificate stores. 2) Pushes can be explicitly enabled for `git://`—both globally and on a per-repository basis. I admit this might make some sense in certain limited circumstances.

Comment: @kostix I deliberately didn't get into the SSL details as they get pretty sticky. I was, however, unaware that you could even *enable* push over `git://` transports! That seems like a terrible idea. I'll add a few footnotes.

Comment: @torek, re. TLS: although complicated, it actually can be used to authenticate both the client (to the server), and the server (to the client), and the robustness of the resulting authentication against MitM attacks is then roughly on par with that of SSH. Re. pushes via `git-deamon`: certainly a silly idea to do in an insecure network but _sometimes_ you do really have what they call controlled environment ;-)